# Can stand-alone Rails server accept requests on multiple IP addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to know if I can launch a Rails server (Puma or otherwise) with options that will allow it to be hit over any IP address (127.0.0.1, localhost, network IP address, etc).

I think `-b` option only takes one IP address (not a wildcard or anything), and I have to restart it changing that option to allow connections over various IP addresses.

```
rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000
```

I would like to hit my server via both a browser on my machine and a browser on my iPhone on my network, and possibly a browser in a VM on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The `127.0.0.1` interface is "local only" and won't accept connections from external sources. What you want is the "all" option:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Where `0.0.0.0` means "accept from all interfaces".

You'll need to access your machine on the local network only if you're using a NAT firewall, which is typically the case. 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, and 172.16.x.x type addresses are not accessible from the public internet.

To make this accessible remotely you'll need a tool like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com).